# Is it possible to configure User.current in origen-sdk?

Tags: origen-sdk

As I started running Origen on WSL Ubuntu, I realized that my User ID was incorrect vs what was expected when I tried to use API that required a login.  This was due to how I named my WSL username.  I see the [Origen docs can handle LDAP](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/users/#LDAP_Integration), is there a way to configure my local copy or Origen to use another username?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix implemented in an impending pull request...

https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/pull/354